# James Bond and the invisible car

Tags: optics

For a seminar paper with the topic "Illusion of Invisibility in the James Bond movies" I have to investigate, whether the invisible car from "die another day" is (at least from a theoretical point of view) physically thinkable.

**The invisible car**
[image]

> Adaptive camouflage / Tiny cameras on all sides project the image they see onto a light-emitting polymer skin on the opposite side / To the casual eye as goog as invisible - Q

Since this is a complex topic, my question is: What are the problems here?

- the texture of the car surface (it must be so good, that there is no shadow of the car on the other side)
- how the surface can show different pictures for different angles (so that it is invisible for 2 or more persons)
- how must the cameras work
- how to hide the little cameras
- what else ?

Comment: The biggest problem here is that you aren't letting light into the car. If light can't get out of the car (because otherwise you'd see the interior from the outside), then it also can't get in. The windows wouldn't work. Maybe you replace them with cameras, but if you're directing some light into the car, then the projected image on the other side would be dimmer or require massive amounts of energy

Comment: I can see the car :)

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a popular account of how it has already been done](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-2110184/Invisible-Mercedes-Scientists-use-LEDs-camera-create-invisible-car.html)

Simply an array of LEDs showing the scene on the other side of the car. However, the use of LEDs or any projection technology is never going to be good enough to match sunlight ie 1kW/sq m at max. Night time is different

Comment: if this is possible, the problem how this can work for different viewpoints still remains.

Comment: Two things: 1) I want to point out that the car is dimmer than the surroundings, like I said above. 2) Come on Dirk! This is a link-only answer. You know those are not allowed

Comment: It cannot work for different viewpoints